# Ionic 2 PWA Upgrading App

Tags: web-applications, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic 2 and PWA, so bear with any silly questions.

I have added browser platform and deployed my Ionic PWA app to my server. However, when I update the deployment on the server, the app (which I installed to my Android by adding the URL to the home screen) does not update.

A couple of questions:

1. How do I tell the App Shell to update the app if it can connect to the server?
2. I switched the flight mode on my phone, the app shell refused to load anything at all, not even the flash screen and instead showed the standard Chrome error.

How do I go about solving the above?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it that's your case. but you should check out if you already removed the comments on the server worker script, that way your app will work offline

Search in the index.html for something like:

```
  <script>
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
    .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
}
```

If you see any comments, remove it.

And answering your first question, you should also clear your cache,

Comment: Yes I have removed the comment. My PWA worked but the above issues remained. Regarding clearing the cache, I cannot ask the users to do this!